# WPF DataGrid header column has extra border

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I am new in WPF and I want to show data from database in WPF DataGrid. Every thing goes well except that in the heading and right corner of the rows, there are some extra borders (which I don't know the name). I don't know how to hide it.
The Code in Xaml file is as below

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" Background="{DynamicResource brushWatermarkBackground}">
                            <DataGrid Name="DgDeviceList" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLinesVisibility="None" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ></DataGrid></Grid>
```

Then I have such styles in App.xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,10" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
        <Setter Property="SeparatorBrush" Value="Transparent"></Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,1,0"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
    </Style>
```

The way I fill the Datagrid in cs file is as below:

```
 DgDeviceList.Columns.Clear();
            DgDeviceList.Items.Refresh();
            DataTable dt = AccessDb.GetDeviceList();
            if (dt != null)
            {
                DgDeviceList.DataContext = dt;
                DataGridTextColumn c1 = new DataGridTextColumn();
                Binding b = new Binding("DeviceName");
                c1.Binding = b;

                c1.Header = "Device Name";
                DgDeviceList.Columns.Add(c1);
                DataGridTextColumn c2 = new DataGridTextColumn();
                Binding b2 = new Binding("DeviceSIM1");
                c2.Binding = b2;

                c2.Header = "SIM Card1";
                DgDeviceList.Columns.Add(c2);
                DataGridTextColumn c3 = new DataGridTextColumn();
                Binding b3 = new Binding("DeviceSIM2");
                c3.Binding = b3;

                c3.Header = "SIM Card 2";
                DgDeviceList.Columns.Add(c3);
                DataGridTextColumn c0 = new DataGridTextColumn();
                Binding b0 = new Binding("PIN");
                c0.Binding = b0;

                c0.Header = "Pin Code";
                DgDeviceList.Columns.Add(c0);
                DataGridTextColumn c4 = new DataGridTextColumn();
                Binding b4 = new Binding("MoreInfo");
                c4.Binding = b4;

                c4.Header = "More Info";
                DgDeviceList.Columns.Add(c4);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogEvents.InLogFile("FillDataGrid:" + ex.Message);
            txtLog.Text = ex.Message + "\n" + txtLog.Text;
        }
```

The output datagrid is as below Image. 
[image]

It has some square in rows and columns divider that I think it's for showing us the rows and columns are resize-able.

Edit
After adding HeadersVisibility="Column" the right corner was removed same as below picture.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just add Header Visibility to data grid

```
<DataGrid HeadersVisibility="Column" Name="DgDeviceList" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLinesVisibility="None" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
```

Comment: Thank you Uday Teja. Adding HeadersVisibility="Column" caused removing the borders in the right corner but in the heading still I have those borders. I have added the new picture.

Comment: once remove right border thickness for DataGridCell

Comment: Removing right border thickness for DataGridCell Doesn't have any change. Thank you any way.